# Extract data from clocking in machine into usable format

Tags: excel, date, range, excel-2010

Here at work we have a fingerprint recognition clocking in machine that allows employees to clock in and out of work.
At the end of each week I export the data from the clocking in machine into excel and manually go through the file and generate a in/out form that shows when each employee clocked in / clocked out.

I am looking for a way to automate this, I use a formula in one of my other excel sheets to find data and pull through information in the same row into a table.

```
=VLOOKUP($K$11,'Data Sheet'!$A$2:$AD$6000,30,FALSE)
```

This works in the sheet that I am using it in but when I try and apply this to the clocking in information I get random bits of information confused in with the data that I am trying to extract.

The layout of the raw data from the clocking in machine is as follows:

```
UID    Name    Status    Action    DateTime
1      Name    1         0/1/2     06/06/16 - 07:30

UID - Unique ID of the employee this is what I am using for reference when extracting data.
Name - Name of employee
Status - 0/1/2 depending on clocking in / clockout / verification
Action - Clocking in Time
DateTime - Clocking out Time
```

I am wanting to pull the data through from the initial form with the structure above into a new sheet with an easier to use format that can be filtered by date range.

so I can select a date between - =TODAY() and 7 days ago.
and insert the UID of the individual and it will pull through the clocking in / out of that employee with the correct information within the date range.

Is this possible with the formula that I am using above?

Comment: part of the problem you are having is that despite having a unique ID, the ID can appear more than once in your UID column.  if I understand correctly each time there is an action there will be a new row.  What you are actually trying to pull with your VLOOKUP is all occurrence, when it really only pulls the first occurrence.

Comment: Is the date time column a string or an excel date time formatted to look that way.  Three simple test:  =isnumber(E2)  =istext(E2)  or does the formatting change when you switch from its current format to general?  Any one of those test should confirm what type of information it is

Comment: Is your date stamp (column E)  in the format of dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are going to go through this process on a weekly basis, I would recommend you build yourself a macro that you can tie to a button so that it only runs when you tell it to run.

If the raw data comes in another file format that excel can read, or another excel file, I would recommend leaving those files untouched and as is for archival and record keeping purposes.  When that info has been copied into Excel in the worksheet you are analysing it in, that is the place to play with the data.  If done right, you should not need multiple copies of the data within your spreadsheet.

I would record a macro, of your import procedure right down to entering formulas in adjacent columns and copying them.  People on here can help you edit your macro afterwards to make it more generic to your needs.

I am going to go on the basis that your date/time stamp is currently not in excel format, but is actually a string.  Seems fairly common for raw data.  let convert your date and time. in an adjacent column.

Lets assume your sample data start in A1 to E1 as a header row with row 2 to 6000 underneath it.

In column F2 we will use to the following formula to strip out the date and time and then recombine them to an excel format.

```
=DATE(MID($E2,6,2),MID($E2,4,2),LEFT($E2,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT($E2,5))
```

That assumes your raw data date is in the format dd/mm/yy.  Once your get your date converted to an excel format, you will be able to do more with it.

After that you can apply Excel's built in filters to reduce the data down to what you are looking for.  you can apply multiple filters on the different columns to have it display what you want.  You can set the filter on the date column to get your date range only to display.  You can then set your UID column filter to only display the person you are looking for.